# Vim: How do you remap the functionality of CTRL-W to a different key?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

I'd like to map CTRL-W to something else, but I'd also like to retain the functionality of CTRL-W, for resizing windows, moving between splits, etc.  So I'd like to move it to something like CTRL-Q.

However, my naive attempt of the following doesn't work quite right:

```
nnoremap <C-Q> <C-W>
nnoremap <C-W> iexamplemapping<esc>
```

CTRL-Q seems to work the same as CTRL-W did previously. But CTRL-W seems to wait for about a second before executing the new mapping.  Is there any way to have it execute it immediately?  Would I have to remap every combination of `<C-W><C-W>`, `<C-W>_`, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I configure just those two mappings I do not see any timeout delay after typing *C-w*. You might want to check if something else (a plugin?) has defined any additional mappings that start with *C-w*:

```
:verbose map <C-W>
```

You will encounter the timeout (see `:help 'ttimeout'`) if you have any other (normal mode) mappings that also start with *C-w*.
E.g. If you also have the mapping `nnoremap <C-w>f ifrob<Esc>` active, you will see a timeout delay after typing a *C-w* (until you type some other character so that Vim can tell whether you wanted the *C-w* mapping, or the *C-w f* mapping).

Comment: Yeah, I had a custom <C-w>[char] mapping that I forgot about  :/ Cheers.